# Trying to delete c# array in c++ dll. Getting System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, c++, exception, dll, dllimport

I've been working with a custom C++ DLL and am having issues with deleting an array in C++ that was passed from C# using [DLLImport]. When it's running its giving me the exception System.AccessViolationException.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
__declspec(dllexport) void empty(Game* x[], int y)
    {
        try
        {
            delete x[y];
        }
        catch (const std::exception& exc)
        {
            // catch anything thrown within try block that derives from std::exception
            ExceptionOutput << exc.what();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only the dll that created the array should delete it.

Comment: Standard C++'s memory management is very different from C#'s. If C# created the object you are deleting C++ likely has no record of it coming from it's own freestore and won't know how to put it back. You'll probably need to provide a function that the C++ code can call to free it.

Comment: show [mcve] so that we can see all the code necessary, since this code does not exist in isolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case C++ and C# code would have different heaps and it is not possible to allocate data in one part and deallocate in another. If the array was created in C# code it should be freed in C# code - basically C# code owns that data and it in charge of reallocating that.

If in your case C++ code knows better when to deallocate the memory it worth creating a function in C# code and export it to C++ code which would call it when it is needed.